# How to solve the jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).treemenu(...).openActive is not a function TypeError?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When including a jQuery function in my JavaScript code, I get the following console error in Chrome: `jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).... is not a function TypeError`

I went through virtually all existing questions related to this issue on Stackoverflow, but couldn't get rid of the error.

First I thought the error was caused by loading jQuery itself, so I tried loading jQuery like this in `functions.php`:

```
function add_jqmigrate_script() {
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js', false, true);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jqm-script2', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.3.1.min.js',array ('jquery'), false, true);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_jqmigrate_script' );
```

Then, I tried loading it within the JavaScript file directly, as follows:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

There is no difference, the error remains.

Then, I tried different variations of the jQuery function, as follows. All of the variations do not change the error message. Interestingly, the script appears to actually work, see [link](https://www.1screener.com/).
I am grateful for any hints or suggestions how to solve this. Thanks!

1)

```
jQuery(function(){
            $(".tree").treemenu({delay:500}).openActive();
});
```

2. 

```
jQuery(function($){
            $(".tree").treemenu({delay:500}).openActive();
});
```

3. 

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(function() {
            $(".tree").treemenu({delay:500}).openActive();
  });
});
```

4. 

```
jQuery(function(){
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".tree").treemenu({delay:500}).openActive();
        });
});
```

Comment: Is there something else in the `$(...)....`?  like `$(...).error is not a function` (just an example)?

Comment: Yes, the full text of the yellow warning in the Chrome console is as follows: `jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).treemenu(...).openActive is not a function TypeError: $(...).treemenu(...).openActive is not a function`

Comment: The actual error message (red) says: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).treemenu(...).openActive is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's some mix up in the versions vs out-dated examples.

In v0.4 there's an `$.fn.openActive` extension and the [demo](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Lightweight-Folding-Menu-Plugin-For-jQuery-treemenu-js/) uses v0.4.  This has been removed in v0.6 (or earlier) and replaced with the `openActive:true` option.

From [changelog](https://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Lightweight-Folding-Menu-Plugin-For-jQuery-treemenu-js.html)

> 2016-11-24
>
> fix styles
> don't touch tree-empty el when use closeOther
> **move fn.openActive() code to fn.treemenu()**

The code for your website (using v0.6) should be (from [github page](https://github.com/xevin/jquery.treemenu.js)):

```
$(function(){
  $(".tree").treemenu({delay:500, openActive:true});
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was it. I had been looking at the completely wrong spot...I appreciate your help!

Comment: Didn't help that the example used the old version - so your code was exactly matching that.  :)